# How to get some values from a special set?

Tags: python

I need to get the rank number from this set:

```
{'rank': 'a=1;b=2;c=3', 'type': 'valid', 'name': 'Mr.A'}
```

I can get the rank value by this:

```
a = {'value': 'rank:a=1;b=2;c=3', 'type': 'valid', 'name': 'Mr.A'}
rank = a['value']
print(rank)
```

And I will get:

```
rank:a=1;b=2;c=3
```

How can I get the number from `rank`?

I want to split this by `';'` and hope output the data like:

```
1,2,3
```

Comment: That "special set" isn't a set, it's a dictionary. That is also not what the `print(rank)` would display — which would be `a=1;b=2;c=3`. It also looks like you want *all* the number for the value, not just a single one. What format do you want them in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the format doesn't change, first split by `:`, and take right part:

```
rank_value = rank.split(':')[1]
```

Then split by `;`, and split each part by `=`, putting them in a list:

```
ranks = [x.split('=')[1] for x in rank_value.split(';')]
```

Then you can join `ranks` to a single string:

```
','.join(ranks)
```

Comment: This work. Thank you. I stuck in split ';' part around a half of day.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.findall` to isolate each number in the rank string:

```py
a = {'value':'rank:a=1;b=2;c=3','type':'valid','name':'Mr.A'}
rank = a['value']
nums = ','.join(re.findall(r'\d+', rank))
print(nums)  # 1,2,3
```

Answer (score -1):

If the variable `a['value']` is always formatted the same, you can use a list comprehension with `isdigit()` function :

```
rank = ','.join([i for i in a['value'] if i.isdigit()])

# Output
'1,2,3'
```

Comment: This won't work for two digit ranks